# Keynote: Long text with Latex symbols

Tags: presentations

I know LaTeXiT can insert equations in to Apple's Keynote software, but I am looking for a tool to insert Latex symbols that integrate into the original text in my Keynote presentation. the inline symbols and equations should blend into the full text, similar to the old TexPoint used for Microsoft Powerpoint. For example, if I input

`Define a graph $$G$$ with set of edges $$E$$ and vertex $$V$$`

I would like a function to convert it into [image]

LaTeXiT supports such conversion in Pages, but not Keynote. (the mock image above is actually a screenshot from Pages)

I can insert long text such as paragraphs and bullet points in my LaTeXiT input window, but that seems not natural, and I have to copy it back into LaTeXiT to edit them.

Comment: `$$` is `tex` command for display math environment. for inline math is defined `$`.

Comment: This is not a direct solution to your question, but perhaps you can typeset the original text with math symbols in LaTeXiT. Below is a screen shot with version 2.10.1. The generated picture can be dragged into Keynote (and PowerPoint for Mac). [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQJUd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQJUd.png)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  This area is reserved for (real) answers.

Comment: The OP already said they could do this, so this really doesn't answer the question. More restates part of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Keynote 8.1 now supports `LaTeX` and `MathML` natively. You can use the `\text{}` command to produce normal text inside a formula, and Keynote uses the font matching the rest of the presentation.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Bobyandbob do you know if the font of the equation can be changed from the default one? and if so, how to change it?

Comment: @bobsacameno i don't know. You should ask a new question with a link to this question here. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Keynote does not support inline graphics, i.e., graphics that floats with the text. Therefore this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Keynote 11.2 [appears to have this functionality](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/keynote/tan72a69d01f/mac) now.

It is not quite as clean as the usual inline LaTeX with $.$, however it does work! Simply write your sentence in a textbox and when you want to insert a maths symbol, use the equation editor (Insert > Equation), write it in TeX (with no $.$), click insert and then it is inline. Moreover, this has the benefit of being easily formatted alongside the rest of the text, e.g. if you change the font size or colour of the sentence, then the TeX will change with it. Very neat!

One wonders if they could implement a simple tool for automatically compiling each instance of $.$ into TeX, but this is a good start that makes it bearable to use Keynote for mathematics presentations.